# Clion : Process finished with exit code 139

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for collage exercise in C++ but I don't know why I see this error

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

it's just for testing the class and it's not complete

in main if I remove the `add('a');` program run successfully but any function call will make this error !

the question is read a tree in bracket/parenthesis form and make a tree in linked list form

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Tree
{
public:
    char data;
    Tree *right;
    Tree *left;
};

Tree *root;
Tree *temp;

void add(char c)
{
    root->data = c;
}

void addR(char c)
{
    temp = new Tree;
    temp->data = c;
    root->right = temp;
}

void addL(char c)
{
    temp = new Tree;
    temp->data = c;
    root->left = temp;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<2;
    add('a');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `root` is uninitialized.

Comment: thank you, it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tree *root;
void add(char c)
{
    root->data = c;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<2;
    add('a'); // <---
    return 0;
}
```

`add('a')` invokes undefined behavior by accessing an uninitialized pointer `root` in `root->data = c;`. You should initialize it first:

```
root = new Tree();
```